# How to get a NSuser default value in another viewcontroller in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults

My requirement is when user entered in to login screen userid will generate that id is stored in nsuserdefault and I want to append this userid with url in another viewcontroller can any one tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate your user id, you can store it in NSUserDefaults like that :

```
NSUserDefaults().setObject(userId, forKey: "userId")
```

Whenever you want to get this userId :

```
let userId = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId")
```

Comment: NSUserDefaults().setObject(userId, forKey: "userId")

Comment: Just a note, You should use NSUserDefaults method stringForKey

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/stringForKey:

Comment: Add ?? "" at the end to prevent it returning nil and unwrap your optional

Comment: let userId = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId") ?? ""

Answer (score 2):

Well first get value of string from defaults

```
 var myOutput: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key")
```

Then append in your desired url

```
 url = url + myOutput
```

and you are golden